# A=$\forall x\in R, \exists y\in R$ s.t. $y\ge x$, $|f(y)|\ge1$, B=$\exists x\in R, \forall y\in R$ s.t. $y\ge x$, $|f(y)|\ge1$. If A then B?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A function is defined type A if:
$f:R \rightarrow R, \forall x\in R, \exists y\in R$ s.t. $y\ge x$ and $|f(y)|\ge1$

A function is defined type b if:
$f:R \rightarrow R, \exists x\in R, \forall y\in R$ s.t. $y\ge x$, $|f(y)|\ge1$

If a function is of type A then is it of Type B?

If a function is of type B then is it of Type A?

I think both are true, but I don't know how to prove it. I ran through some examples and I couldn't think of one that would be A and not B or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=2$ for $x$ rational and $0$ for $x$ irrational. Then $f$ is of type A but not type B.

$f(x)=\sin x$ is a continuous function of type A which is not f type B.

[ Given any real number $y=\frac {\pi} 2+2n\pi$ ($n$ a positve integer) satisfies $|f(x)|=|1|=1$ and $y \geq x$ if we choose $n$ large enough. Hence $\sin x$ is of type A. It is not of type B because  $y=\pi +2n\pi$ gives $|sin (y)|=0<1$ and $y \geq x$ if we choose $n$ large enough].

Any function of type B is of type A: suppose there exists $x_0$ such that $|f(y)| \geq 1$ whenever $y \geq x$. Let $x$ be any real number. If $y >\max \{x_0,x\}$ then $|f(y)| \geq 1$ and this proves that $f$ is of type A.

Comment: Sorry how are those of type A but not B?

Comment: @DylanY I have added a proof for the second example. For the first one all you need is the fact given any real number $x$ there is a rational number greater than $x$ as well as  an irrational number greater than $x$.

Comment: awesome. What about the inverse?

Comment: Any function of type B is of type A. @DylanY

Comment: How would you prove it?

Comment: @DylanY See my answer now.